# font awesome 4 - how to align SVGs?

Tags: font-awesome, font-awesome-4

The font awesome 4 code generates these SVGs which are not target-able with typical CSS, which sucks, and breaks my entire codebase.

In the past, you could make an `<i>` tag, and style it like everything else, but now that these SVGs get generated in the DOM, you can't use `text-align` or `margin`, etc.

I've tried wrapping the icons in divs, but this is still limited and cannot affect the icon itself when it comes to alignment within the div.

So this:

```
        <div class="tradeoff-cell">
            <span class="tradeoff-title">Lower Cap</span>
            <div class="tradeoff-icon">
                <i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Becomes this:

```
<div class="tradeoff-cell">
    <span class="tradeoff-title">Lower RL Rate</span>
    <div class="tradeoff-icon"><svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-chart-line fa-w-16" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fa" data-icon="chart-line" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M500 384c6.6 0 12 5.4 12 12v40c0 6.6-5.4 12-12 12H12c-6.6 0-12-5.4-12-12V76c0-6.6 5.4-12 12-12h40c6.6 0 12 5.4 12 12v308h436zM456 96H344c-21.4 0-32.1 25.9-17 41l32.9 32.9-72 72.9-55.6-55.6c-4.7-4.7-12.2-4.7-16.9 0L96.4 305c-4.7 4.6-4.8 12.2-.2 16.9l28.5 29.4c4.7 4.8 12.4 4.9 17.1.1l82.1-82.1 55.5 55.5c4.7 4.7 12.3 4.7 17 0l109.2-109.2L439 249c15.1 15.1 41 4.4 41-17V120c0-13.3-10.7-24-24-24z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fa fa-line-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i> -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's hard as hell to align those SVGs, I was tearing my hair out. Use FA5, it handles SVG far better.

Comment: But if FA5 still makes the SVG's, what do you do to get them to align?

Comment: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js